# AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput supposedly bad configuration

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, core-audio

AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput seems incredibly picky.

Let's say I have two MP4s (well-formed; play back 100% fine in a variety of environments, created with the following settings on an iPhone (AVCaptureData...)):

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{
    AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(1),
    AVSampleRateKey:  @(44100.0),
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: @(64000),
    AVChannelLayoutKey: currentChannelLayoutData // pulled from CMSampleBuffer/etc
};
```

All good, so I am lead to believe. Now let's say I take these two MP4s and I want to combine them with the whole MutableComposition drill - if I export this composition/videoComposition/audioMix with, say, AVAssetExportSession, it works totally fine and flawlessly.

Now for a variety of reasons I don't want to use AVAssetExportSession; thus, we wind up with something similar to the following (the entire asset-writing experience surrounding this is fairly standard):

```
NSError *error;
_assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:_composition error:&error];
NSArray *videoTracks = [_assetReader.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

_videoOutput = [AVAssetReaderVideoCompositionOutput
                assetReaderVideoCompositionOutputWithVideoTracks:videoTracks
                videoSettings:@{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)}];
_videoComposition.renderScale = 1.0f;
_videoOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = NO;
_videoOutput.videoComposition = _videoComposition;

if([_assetReader canAddOutput:_videoOutput])
    [_assetReader addOutput:_videoOutput];
else
    SNLog(@"Could not add video reader");

NSArray *audioTracks = [_composition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
_audioOutput = [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:audioTracks audioSettings:@{AVFormatIDKey: [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM]}];
_audioOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = NO;
if(_audioMix)
    _audioOutput.audioMix = _audioMix;


if([_assetReader canAddOutput:_audioOutput])
    [_assetReader addOutput:_audioOutput];
else
    SNLog(@"Could not add audio mix output");
```

Upon trying to call startWriting with all of this I wind up with the following error:

```
**Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11822 "Cannot Open" UserInfo=0x16df24d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open, NSUnderlyingError=0x16deecb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12413.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media format is not supported.}**
```

What am I missing here? This error doesn't really tell me anything useful; my setup seems to be very close to others I've seen documented around the web, too. I don't think this is that exotic.

This setup seemed to be working fine last week, and now all I get are hiccups. The input audio for the conversion writer is using the same audio settings dict pasted at the top. I would love it if I'm just missing some stupid detail here.

iOS7, iPhone 5 for what it's worth. AudioSesson category/mode are PlayAndRecord/etc; app records videos with AVAssetWriter/co just fine, but blows up at this point. No audio session changes/interruptions/etc occur at any point here.

Comment: `This setup seemed to be working fine last week` so what have you changed?

Comment: Nothing, which is why this is so odd.

Comment: Are you using VCS to really make sure you (or someone else!) didn't change anything?

Comment: I would wager it's a good bet that anyone working on a large project in this day and age uses a VCS. Sometimes those people go a bit without committing though. ;P

Comment: its because you smell bad and you cant read good